# Check Windows last backup with Linux Nagios

Tags: unix, windows-server-2008-r2, nagios

How can I check a Windows Server latest backup date from a Unix system and monitor it through Nagios?

Basically I want to throw an Alert if the last backup was over a day ago

I thought I could use check_file_age but it didn't work and there's probably a better alternative.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which file are you trying to monitorize in windows?
Are you using NSClient++ ?

EDIT:

If you are using NSClient++ you can use check_nt for that. Try this:

```
define service{
use generic-service
host_name   servername
service_description     File changed
check_command   check_nt! FILEAGE -l "your_file_location"! -w 300 -c 600 
}
```

source: https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=25956

Comment: They are backup files, I just created a folder in C: called "Backup" to test if it works. I created a random text file there to test. I am using NSClient++, SSL handshake is working too so I am free to use nrpe aswell.